# Get Form values in Python using Django framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My question here is without using `Model` or `forms.Form` can we get form values on submit using Django `request` object.

Here is small example to explain problem.

**HTML Code :**

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="USERNAME" class="text" value="USERNAME" >
    <input type="password" id="Password" value="Password" >
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="LOGIN">
    </div>  
    <p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
</form>
```

**views.py Code :**

```
def dologin(request):
    print('i am in do login')
    print(request.method)
    print(request.POST)
    for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
        print(key , value)

    return render(request,'webapp/login.html')
```

So here my key values are empty always. I have learned and capable enough to create html forms using `Model` and `forms:Form`. But to add more style changes I need to map this `forms:Form` object to html defined form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a name to each input

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="USERNAME" class="text" name="USERNAME" value="USERNAME" >
    <input type="password" id="Password" value="Password" name="Password" >
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="LOGIN">
    </div>  
    <p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML form elements always need a `name` attribute, otherwise the browser won't have any way of sending them to the backend. It's that attribute that is the key in the POST dict.

Note that any formatting you can do with HTML on its own you can also do with Django forms; you really should use them in most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the HTML attribute using name for every form component.